# Replace multiple occurrences of words in html of page

Tags: javascript, html

How can I replace some words in the html without losing event bindings ?

I want to replace all occurrences of word 'Delivery' by 'Pickup' on html page

Suggested approaches :

1. Get the html of page and store it in variable say 'content'
2. replace word in 'content' variable through regex  (updated_content = content.replace(/Delivery/ig,'pickup'));
3. update page html by updated_content

But this approach wipes out all the event binding on page

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Maybe event delegation? Like binding events to window, document or some higher parent and make use of event bubbling?

Answer (score 0):

If you would use jQuery:

```
$("*:not(html, table, tbody, tr):contains('" + yourSearchPhrase + "')").each(function(index, item) {
  item.innerText = item.innerText.replace(yourSearchPhrase, replacementText);
});
```

Comment: It selects all those nodes containing the text and their grand parents as  well, and updating the grandparent html wipesout all event bindings

Can u limit it to immediate parents.